# Can't get vscode to display through x windows

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, amazon-ec2, x11-forwarding, xming

Trying to run vscode remotely, and display it back to my Windows machine.

Working on Amazon EC2 instance, logging in through putty and using x-ming for the xserver on Windows. I can launch and display an xterm window, I can launch and display a nautilus browser. When I launch vscode, first I'll get a pop-up saying I need to change the permissions on a /run/user file - that pop-up is obviously also displaying correctly. Once the permission has been set, I can launch (vs)code and see it running in the background (through ps -ef | grep code), but nothing displays back. When using a virtual desktop being hosted on Amazon, and using cygwin x-server, I can launch and display vs code just fine - but I can't use cygwin  on my development machine. Any ideas?